# Spark - Worker doesn't have sufficient resource

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-manager

I am new to Apache Spark and Cloudera Manager.I met some problem running my first spark application.

There are two Virtual Machines in my cluster with RAM and Cores:

> 13.4G /4 Cores as Master Node ,node01
>
> 4G / 4 Cores as Slave Node ,node02

When I run 
`su - hdfs -c "spark-shell --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1"`

it shows

> WARN cluster.YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

I don't know where to configure these parameters to make it through.

FYI,I can access http://node01:8088 to check on yarn web ui that several resource is N/A:
[image]
Also,Spark History Server shows executors parameters are almost all 0.(I don't exactly understand what they mean though)
[image]

Could anyone please show me how to config this mess so that I can run spark applications smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

In Cloudera Manager go to "YARN > Configuration" and search for these:

- Container Memory Maximum -> set this to 4GB
- Container Memory -> set this to 16G
- Container Virtual CPU Cores Maximum -> 1
- Container Virtual CPU Cores -> 4

Once done, restart YARN and retry running your app.

You'll be over-provisioning resources for YARN (by setting Container Memory to 16GB you are saying that you are dedicating 16GB just for YARN apps, while you have just 4GB (for yarn, other services, OS...) on your worker node), but hopefully your app will run. If not, try lowering your memory from 16GB -> 8GB and cores from 4 -> 2.

This would be a good read: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-16-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html